# Heroku Node/React Deployment Routes Everything to index.html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli, nodejs-server

I have an `app.js` node main file where I define my api path as the following

`app.get('/api/users', UserController.get);`

Below in the same file I have the following

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./front/build")));
app.get("*", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./front/build", "index.html"));
});
```

The `index.html` successfully serves React App.

If I open my heroku app somewhere at [my-app.herokuapp.com](http://google.com) it will open the React app which is intended but the Problem is [my-app.herokuapp.com/api/users](http://google.com) also serves index.html file instead of JSON that the endpoint is supposed to return.

**I tried** 
I replaced endpoint route definition to come before the "*" definition (didn't suffice)


EVEN more, I removed redirection to index.html but heroku still opens the index.html page with any type of request (the "*" redirection still works). So, it might have cached something?

Is it about cache (how to clean?) or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should create routes and work in a proper flow for each functionality,
**For Example**:
//app.js

```
app.use("/api/user",userRoutes);
```

//UserRoutes

```
router.post("/signup",UserController.signup);
```

//UserController

```
exports.signup = async (req,res,next) => {
    //Signup function to add a new user  when the user provides required info
```

}

In this way, you code will be easily accessible and much efficient